# Fix css error on Iphone

Tags: css, iphone

The problematic pages are:

http://www.to-hawaii.com/oahu/accommodations and 
http://www.to-hawaii.com/oahu/vacationrentals

Please see these pages with an iPhone and notice how the sidebar appears in front of the content. Other pages such as http://www.to-hawaii.com/oahu/beaches work correctly: content first, followed by sidebar.

I am using flexbox to achieve this set up and this is my code:

```
#wrapper {    
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;

    }
.rightpanel {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    -webkit-order: 2;
    order: 2;
}
.midpanel {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    -webkit-order: 1;
    order: 1;
}
}
```

But for whatever reason this doesn't work on the pages above.

Comment: I think I figured out the issue. The problem is with a Google ad, not my code.

Comment: I assume I checked it after the fix? The links behave the same.